# Does SQS allow retry events within deduplication period?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I am using FIFO SQS queue to process ordered events. And my lambda pulls the messages from the queue. There is a deduplication id to avoid processing duplicate messages from the queue and the interval is 5 minutes.

I also enabled retry in the queue and the visibility time is 2 minutes. If the message failed to process and a retry happens in 2 minutes with the same deduplication id, does SQS delivers the message to the target application?

Comment: What do you mean by "delivers the message to the target application"? Amazon SQS is a 'pull model' where the application needs to request a message from the queue. What do you mean by "retry happens"? Do you mean the application calls `ReceiveMessage()`? Please Edit your question to clarify details.

Comment: Lambda will retry the message if it fails to process it. It is done automatically via configuring SQS visibility time. The question is that does SQS consider the retry event as duplicate event?

Comment: Your question does not mention the use of AWS Lambda. Please Edit your question to add appropriate information.